# Update DynamoDB item using DynamoDBMapper in Java

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, distributed-computing

How can I update DynamoDB item using DynamoDBMapper?

I have multiple processes, using the DynamoDB table, thus, get + save will create inconsistency. I can not find the method to update the item using DynamoDBMapper.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The **`save()`** method will perform the `putItem` or `updateItem` based on the value set in **SaveBehavior**. Please refer the below description. There is no update method in DynamoDBMapper class because of this reason. However, there is a separate delete method available.

> Saves an item in DynamoDB. The service method used is determined by
>   the DynamoDBMapperConfig.getSaveBehavior() value, to use either
>   AmazonDynamoDB.putItem(PutItemRequest) or
>   AmazonDynamoDB.updateItem(UpdateItemRequest):
>
> **UPDATE (default) :**
>   UPDATE will not affect unmodeled attributes on a save operation and a
>   null value for the modeled attribute will remove it from that item in
>   DynamoDB. Because of the limitation of updateItem request, the
>   implementation of UPDATE will send a putItem request when a key-only
>   object is being saved, and it will send another updateItem request if
>   the given key(s) already exists in the table.
>
> **UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES :** Similar to UPDATE except that it ignores
>   any null value attribute(s) and will NOT remove them from that item in
>   DynamoDB. It also guarantees to send only one single updateItem
>   request, no matter the object is key-only or not.
>
> **CLOBBER :** CLOBBER
>   will clear and replace all attributes, included unmodeled ones,
>   (delete and recreate) on save. Versioned field constraints will also
>   be disregarded. Any options specified in the saveExpression parameter
>   will be overlaid on any constraints due to versioned attributes.

**Example usage:-**

```
DynamoDBMapperConfig dynamoDBMapperConfig = new DynamoDBMapperConfig(SaveBehavior.UPDATE);
```

**UPDATE** DynamoDBMapperConfig (aws sdk 1.11.473) constructor seems to be deprecated and the builder should be used instead:

```
DynamoDBMapperConfig dynamoDBMapperConfig = new DynamoDBMapperConfig.Builder()
  .withConsistentReads(DynamoDBMapperConfig.ConsistentReads.CONSISTENT)
  .withSaveBehavior(DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior.UPDATE)
  .build();
dynamoDBMapper.save(yourObject, dynamoDBMapperConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

To have consistency in your dynamo db write operations you will have to choose one option between Optimistic locking and Conditional writes.

Here are the links to AWS documentation which may help you;

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptimisticLocking.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html