# AWS object single attribute update

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I updating an dynamo db table item from android application and it is updating complete item.But I am not getting how should I update single attribute instead of complete object.Please let me know if there is any way to do so.

I am using **save()** method of **DynamoMapper** for updating item.

Comment: Can you show some snippet on how you use `save()`?

Comment: This seems to answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40153954/1865297

Comment: Thanks @AbhayaChauhan It worked .